# Best way to extract number of partitions?

Tags: linux, bash

Assuming that there are only primary partitions on a disk, what is the best way to find the current number of partitions?

Is there any better way than:

```
fdisk -l > temp
#Following returns first column of the last line of temp e.g. /dev/sda4
lastPart=$(tail -n 1 temp | awk '{print $1}')
totalPartitions=$(echo ${lastPart:8})
```

**$totalPartitions** variable sometimes returns **NULL**. That's why, I was wondering if there is a more reliable way to find the current number of partitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about:

```
totalPartitions=$(grep -c 'sda[0-9]' /proc/partitions)
```

?

(Where `sda` is the name of the disk you're interested in, replacing it as appropriate)

Comment: Thanks. That's more efficient solution.

Comment: Note that this while most UNIX-like operating systems support procfs, only Linux (afaik) supports non-process-related information (such as /proc/partitions). In other words, this is likely to fail on, for example, FreeBSD.

Comment: For some reason SO just told me "this comment may no longer be edited" when I edited my above post, so I'm adding this one instead. Daft.

Additionally (Linux-specific too,) 'sdX' will only work on a reasonably modern system as older Linux kernels differentiate between drives using PATA or SCSI (as you might recall, PATA drives traditionally turned up as 'hdX').

Comment: not all block devices are sdX formatted names.  think about the old hd series,  and the less old mmcblk (memory cards), and vdX (disks in virtual machines), and loop devices, they can have partitions too.

Comment: @billy: Yes, the question asked about counting the partitions on a (single) disk, so presumably you would know the name of the disk you were interested in.  I've updated the question to make that hopefully clear.

Comment: @caf I still think /proc/partitions is archaic.  I've updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

I found this question while I was writing a script to safely wipe test and re-provision storage, which is sometimes a memory card, so mmcblk0p1 is often the format of its partitions.

Here's my answer:

```
diskICareAbout="sda"
totalPartitions="$( ls  /sys/block/${diskICareAbout}/*/partition  | wc -l )"
```

/proc/partitions is archaic and flat.  The sys filesystem can comunicate the heirarchal nature of partitions well enough that grep is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use partx for this.

```
partx -g /dev/<disk> | wc -l
```

will return the total number of partitions (`-g` omits the header line). To get the last partition on a disk, use

```
partx -rgo NR -n -1:-1 /dev/<disk>
```

which may be useful if there are gaps in the partition numbers. `-r` omits aligning spaces, and `-o` specifies the comma-separated columns to include. `-n` specifies a range of partitions `start:end`, where `-1` is the last partition.

Comment: I don't know why this is was downvoted. It's not portable outside of Linux, but neither are the other answers really. And partx has a much cleaner output than fdisk that can be integrated in to scripts very easily. Thanks for the tip on this tool that I've never used before.